# How to boot using Windows 11 installation files on a hard drive not USB

Tags: windows, installation

Trying to boot using windows 11 installation files from a hard drive (not USB). So far I created an EFI partition manually and another partition for the installation files from windows 11 ISO disk. But is not able to configure the EFI partition to point to the actual installation files.

[image: Disk Management screen capture]

Tried using bcdedit and bcdboot but says cannot find boot files. Not sure how to proceed.